# How can you create a Visual Studio extension that references a class library project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm having an issue creating a Visual Studio Extension that calls into another project. I've put a trivial example up on github: https://github.com/craigguest/HelloWorldVSIX

In this example I simply have a "Invoke HelloWorld Command" item in the tools menu that gets it's message from a static property in another project (Message.Text). However, I get this error when clicking the item:

[image: VS 2017 Extension Error Message]

I have added the project as an asset in the manifest, and added the ProvideBindingPath attribute to my package class but I still get the error.

Anything you can do to help would be appreciated, not much is turning up in searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sign your class library project with package project key.snk.

right click project named HelloWorld -> Properties -> signing -> enable sign the assembly -> click the dropdownlist below -> Browser... -> select key.snk file in the project named HelloWorld2Parter -> Open -> rebuild your project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cole, the video was a nice touch. I've removed the key from my main project and it works. I'll do a bit more reading on how to work with key files on public repositories before I do much more development though.